# Throw multiple exceptions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception

I'm wondering if there is a way to throw multiple errors and catch all of them in JavaScript.

I'm looking for specific fields, and when I find a missing one I would like to throw an error.

The problem is that if I throw a single error, like:

```
throw "you are missing field: " xxxxxx
```

I'm not telling the user all of the other fields which he/she is missing.

I would also not like to combine everything into a single string, since the error message might be too long.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Collect your error message in any collection (array or object) and at the last check it and throw exception accordingly

Comment: It is a bad practice to use an exceptions for handling this kind of errors

Comment: @MaxZuber Could you please explain the reason why it's bad?

Answer (score 6):

You create your own type of `Error` that holds the list of missing fields:

```
class MissingFieldsError extends Error {
  constructor(fields, ...params) {
    super(...params);
    this.fields_ = fields;
  }

  getMissingFields() {
    return this.fields_;
  }
}
```

To use it, you can gather all of the missing fields first and then throw an instance of `MissingFieldsError`.
Assuming you have some sort of array of `Field` instances, the code should look like this:

```
const missingFields = fields
    .filter((field) => field.isMissing())
    .map((field) => field.getName());

if (missingFields.length > 0) {
  throw new MissingFieldsError(
      missingFields, 'Some required fields are missing.');
}
```

If you prefer, you can even have separate `Error`s thrown, collect them and then throw the `MissingFieldsError`:

```
const missingFields = [];

fields.forEach((field) => {
  try {
    const value = field.getValue();
    // Process the field's value.

    // Could be just field.validate();
  } catch (e) {
    missingFields.push(field.getName());
  }
});

if (missingFields.length > 0) {
  throw new MissingFieldsError(
      missingFields, 'Some required fields are missing.');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can throw any kind of object, you're not limited to strings, so you might as well collect your error messages into an object, and throw that in the end, if any errors were present.

Comment: Ok so if I have an object, how would that actually be thrown so that I display all the errors that were caught?

If it is an Array, I can just do something like this right?
for each(error in errorArray){ throw error; }

Comment: No, you cannot do that, because the first throw statement surrenders your command flow. If you want to catch all errors separately, I think you need to chain them somehow, but it would be easier if you caught and handled them all at the same place.

Comment: If you throw an object, instead of an instance of error, you won't automatically get a stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

Hey so currently dealing with an issue related to this. Just wanted to add a couple thoughts.

[`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) allows you to throw any expression and it will generate an exception which will kick into the `catch` clause if it exists with the value populated as the parameter (typically an `Error`). This is user-defined though so you can essentially throw whatever you want.

So if you really wanted to throw an array of exceptions, you totally can. i.e. something like this

```
try {
  var errors = [];
  for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    errors.push(new Error('Here is a special exception'));
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    throw errors; 
  }

} catch(e) {
    for (let i=0; i<e.length; i++) {
      console.log(e[i]);
    }
}
```

I think some things to be aware of

- can your function throw different types? If you can throw arrays, numbers, exceptions, any other expressions, you'll need to handle all those cases. Generally people will move this into their own error handler, so you'll need to handle collections in this case
- be careful of [nested try/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Nested_try-blocks) statements. You would normally need to be aware of this but throwing it out there (haha!) anyways for sanity purposes.
- When handling async code where errors can get populated into the array at different times, make sure to utilize `await` and `Promise.all` before going through (unless you don't mind missing out on exceptions).

In terms of how good/bad practice it is, I honestly couldn't find much about it. I would say tread lightly and understand if your use case really needs this. Sometimes it's helpful but you may not need to process the entire array of exceptions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I basically throw errors from my service classes or service methods with exact exception names so that later we can handle them according to the exception name like the following

```
try{
    const user = User.findOne({ _id: request.body.user_id });
    
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error ("USER_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION")
    }
    
    const articles = Article.find({ user_id: user._id });
    
    if (!articles) {
        throw new Error ("USER_ARTICLES_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION")
    }

    //Rest of the code goes below
    return response.status(200).json({
        status: "success"
    });
}catch(error) {
    /** Handle specific exceptions */
    if (error.message == "USER_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION") {
        return response.status(400).json({
            status: "error",
            message: "User details not found."
        });
    }

    if (error.message == "USER_ARTICLES_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION") {
        return response.status(400).json({
            status: "error",
            message: "User articles not found."
        });
    }

    /** Handle generic exceptions */
    return response.status(400).json({
        status: "error",
        message: error.message
    });
}
```